# join results from multiple hosts in ansible

Tags: ansible

I'd like to use ansible to collect a fingerprint from multiple hosts and join the results with a separator in one new variable. This variable is then used in other tasks for all hosts.

```yaml
- name: Collect fingerprint
  become: yes
  command: cut -d" " -f2 {{ dataDir }}/{{ name }}_{{ port }}/fingerprint
  register: fingerprint

- name: Debug output
  debug:
    msg: fingerprints {{ fingerprint.stdout | join(',') }}
```

output of "Collect fingerprint":

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAA  
BBBBBBBBBBBBB  
CCCCCCCCCCCC
```

expected string:
`AAAAAAAAAAAAA,BBBBBBBBBBBBB,CCCCCCCCCCCC`

Can someone please help?

Comment: From your current description I do not understand where and how multiple Remote Nodes and multiple result, the registered fingerprints will come in place.

Comment: the fingerprint will be fetched from multiple hosts and stored in the variable "fingerprint". It should then be joined by "," into one variable

Answer (score 1):

Given two remote hosts

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /tmp/fingerprint
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_13 cat /tmp/fingerprint
XXX
YYY
ZZZ
```

Q: ***"fingerprint will be fetched from multiple hosts and stored in the variable fprint."***

A: Fetch the files and register the variable *fprint*

```yaml
    - command: cat /tmp/fingerprint
      register: fprint
```

Q: ***"It should then be joined by `,` into one variable"***

A: Declare the variable *fprints*

```yaml
  fprints: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                    zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                        map('extract', hostvars, ['fprint', 'stdout_lines'] ))) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  fprints:
    test_11:
    - AAA
    - BBB
    - CCC
    test_13:
    - XXX
    - YYY
    - ZZZ
```

and join the items

```yaml
  fprints_join: "{{ fprints|json_query('*')|flatten|join(',') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  fprints_join: AAA,BBB,CCC,XXX,YYY,ZZZ
```

Optionally,

```yaml
  fprints_join: "{{ fprints|json_query('*')|map('join')|join(',') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  fprints_join: AAABBBCCC,XXXYYYZZZ
```